# How to get data about a place from a stored Google Places reference and/or id?

Tags: angularjs, google-places-api

I am building an app with Angular 1.1.5. It has a Google Place autocomplete and I store the place id and reference on my backend.

I would like to **fetch the places JSON on the client side** (formatted address and name: **no details and no map**) based on the stored place id and reference. This is because I prefer not to store the places data on my server.

I have the following "silly" service:

```
angular.module('MyServices')
  .factory 'GooglePlaces', ($http) ->
      $http {
         method: 'GET'
         url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=CmRYAAAAciqGsTRX1mXRvuXSH2ErwW-jCINE1aLiwP64MCWDN5vkXvXoQGPKldMfmdGyqWSpm7BEYCgDm-iv7Kc2PF7QA7brMAwBbAcqMr5i1f4PwTpaovIZjysCEZTry8Ez30wpEhCNCXpynextCld2EBsDkRKsGhSLayuRyFsex6JA6NPh9dyupoTH3g&sensor=true&key=MYAPPKEY'
}
```

I works great in a web browser, but I get a `is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error.

What is the best practice to get data from place id and reference?

Comment: request the details via the places-library: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_requests

Comment: Well, that is the point of my question: you suggest `service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.getDetails(request, callback);`, but this means I have to instantiate a `map` object and fetch all details. That's the bold part of my question ;)

Comment: You don't need a map when you want to use data returned by the placesService, when you use the data without a map, you must show the "powered by google-logo" instead : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#LogoRequirements